# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from mantisconnect

Tags: soap, mantis

Recently I am trying to integrate two system we use now.
We have a customer feedback website that using Helpspot (http://www.helpspot.com/) and the other is Bug tracker Mantis server. we hope some of customer feedback can be added into mantis . Since mantis have a WSDL mantisconnect, so I wrote some code with nusoap to interact with the mantis wsdl. It worked fine..I can update issue or do rest of other things.

But when I uploaded the same code to the Helpspot server, it stop working...

and I got this error msg:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://Mymantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?WSDL' : Extra content at
>   the end of the document in
>   /www/eh17275/public_html/custom_code/RequestPush-MantisBT.php:36 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /www/eh17275/public_html/custom_code/RequestPush-MantisBT.php(36):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('http://testmant...') #1
>   /www/eh17275/public_html/custom_code/RequestPush-MantisBT.php(75):
>   RequestPush_MantisBT->push('test') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /www/eh17275/public_html/custom_code/RequestPush-MantisBT.php on line
>   36

the Line 36 in my code is =>`$client=new soapclient('http://Mymantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?WSDL');`

I googled whole day and most of people encountered this error usually because they wrote their own SOAP server, but in my case, I just wrote a client and the code worked.

and the WSDL on my mantis server is up. I can see this page `http : / /mymantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php` and I even want my friend at home to check the page and they can see it. So I think the factor of internet service setting can be elimiated.

Is there any people have any thought about this?

Thx for reading

Comment: I uploaded the same code to several web hosting space and in one of the website(byethost), my code work as in my test environment. I notice byethost use the same version PHP as mine which is ver.5.3.14

Comment: and 2 other server which my code doesn't work on are 000webhost =>PHP ver.5.2.17 and the helpspot(the one i mentioned b4) PHP version 5.3.2. So somehow this is caused by environment setting ... I don't know very well about configuration maybe it have something to do about the config on the server not php version... 
Anyone know about any things in the environment could cause this?

Comment: the problem has been solved by two way: one is turn off SOAP on the server, another is use $client=new nusoap_client($endpoint); instead of $client=new soapclient($endpoint); because SOAP running on server use the same key word "soapclient" too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are simply trying with a wrong URL ?
The URL you tested was `http://Mymantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?WSDL` but IMO it should end with `?wsdl`.

I tested with the online [demo site](http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/) :

1. http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?WSDL does nothing
2. http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl works and renders the awaited WSDL document